Some questions on a paper of Rellich
I was trying to read the paper "Über das asymptotische Verhalten der Lösungen von $\Delta u+\lambda u =0$ in unendlichen Gebieten" by Franz Rellich (MR17816, Zbl 0028.16401).

Since it is in German is there any English version available?
Also one of the key results of paper seems to be the non-existence of $L^2$ solution of the equation $\Delta f=-\lambda f$ in the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:|x|>R_0\}$?.

I am just curious to know whether this holds true for any other smooth Riemannian manifold or for eigenfunctions of some other operator other than a Laplacian? Any intuition/comment will also be very helpful.

Unfortunately I do not read german, too. Having a look at the proof I think it is the usual one (maybe he was the first) using expansion in spherical harmonics and asymptotic behavior of Bessel functions.

And any comment regarding the last question?

I do not know and looks delicate. The result is false for $\lambda=0$ where one can construct solutions tending to 0 at infinty as any power.

This is more a long comment than an answer, to show that $L^2$ solutions may exist in some cases. A simple example is $D^2+D+k^2$ in 1d which has solution $e^{-\alpha x}$ with $2\alpha=1+ \sqrt{1-4k^2}$ ($x >0)$. This is due to the drift term. A more involved example is for $|x| \geq 1$ the pure second order operator
$$
L=\Delta+a \sum_{i,j}\frac{x_ix_j}{|x|^2}D_{ij} \quad a>-1.
$$
If $u$ is radial and $Lu+k^2 u=0$ then $(1+a)D_{rr}u+\frac{n-1}{r}D_r u +k^2 u=0$ or $D_{rr}u+\frac{n-1}{(1+a)r}D_r u +\lambda^2 u=0$ with $\lambda^2=k^2/(1+a)$. This is reduced to a Bessel type equation as for the Laplacian writing $u=r^{\frac{1-n}{2(1+a)}}v$ and $v$ is asymptotic to a $\sin r$ for large $r$ since $\lambda^2>0$. This gives $$u^2 \leq \frac{C}{r^{\frac{n-1}{1+a}}}$$
so that $u \in L^2$  at infinity if $-1<a<0$ is properly chosen.

True. Again sorry for asking but can one expect a similar sort of result at least for bi-laplacian which is a higher-order generalisation of laplacian. I actually couldn't read the above-mentioned paper as it's in German but in such eigenvalue problems, one way people do an estimate is by lifting it to a harmonic function by adding one extra variable. As that seems not possible even for bi-Laplacian, I don't know whether there are any bypass of lifting techniques for other operators. Again if you have any idea, any comment would be helpful.

I did not try the trick of lifting, could work. For higher order operaots I do not know but radial computations could work for the bilaplacian....with a lot of effort.

Actually, I was thinking about it yesterday, the issue is this kind of function $e^{-\lambda t}f(x)$ where $(x,t)\in \mathbb{R}^n\times(0,\infty)$ which works for eigenvalue problem for laplacian to lift it to harmonic function doesn't work for higher-order case. So, I am not sure what then could be possible candidates for lifting actually exponential is a nice candidate as it's always non-negative but I am not sure what could be possible candidate for lifting in this case?

As you mentioned that trick of lifting could work for higher order, any idea what would be a possible candidate for lifting? It seems $e^{\lambda t}f(x)$ kind of functions not going to work.

I do not know how to use lifting for the problem you asked, even for the Laplacian. The exponential factor can be very large at infinity, or one shoud restrict on a strip. Do you know how to use in the simplest case? For higher order one could use a complex lambda, for example $\lambda^4=-k^2$

Ok let me think this for some time. I also don't know, I am just trying to think using the techniques I have some idea.
